How to receive new email notifications when accessing email services exclusively with Firefox Android app (no email app installed)?
I'm using the Firefox app on Android 14 to access email services. I don't have any dedicated email apps installed. - I'm doing everything through Firefox.
Is there a way to make Firefox run in the background so that when I receive a new email, I get a notification? Importantly, the notification should be sent by Firefox itself, perhaps with an add-on or similar mechanism.
I'm looking for a solution that works entirely within Firefox, without relying on external email clients.
Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

If your webmailer supports Web Push Notifications Firefox should be able to get you new mail notifications. If not you need a plugin specific for your webmail system. Unfortunately you forgot to tell us which webmail system/provider you use.

@Robert thanks. I'm using gmail, outlook and protonmail with multiple accounts on each. At least for gmail I know for sure that I have desktop notifications toggled on. I don't know if that's what talking about.
